# New features of Objectify4?

Tags: objectify

I could not find any document highlighting the new features to come in Objectify 4. Maybe somebody could shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best documentation, other than combing through the mailing list archives, is here:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/DesignObjectify4

I apologize for not having rolled out real documentation yet, but startup life just hasn't afforded the time yet.  It will.